# Sun GridEngine finished jobs working directory

Tags: sungridengine

Is there any possibility to check SGE finished jobs working directory?

In running/pending jobs there is `cwd` or `sge_o_workdir` variable under `qstat -j job-ID` but no such info is contained in `qacct -j job_ID`. Or maybe there is another way, maybe via bash history (I think there might be an option to check from what directory a qstat command has been executed, which printed job-id number to the shell).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there isn't a direct way to retrieve the working directory of finished jobs with SGE using qacct -j job-ID